# Code to find an angle theta

Tags: math, vector, geometry, trigonometry

So I have 3 3D Vectors, W, T1 and T2 that satisfy the relationship W = T1*cos(theta) + T2*sin(theta).

I need to come up with an algorithm that can find theta given these 3 vectors. However I'm stuck and don't know where to start even.

Comment: Just to check: there is no prior information about angle between T1 and T2? (like "they are always orthogonal")

Answer (score 1):

If T1 and T2 are not collinear, you can use cross product:

- W = T1*cos(theta) + T2*sin(theta)
- [W,T1]=[T2,T1]*sin(theta)
- [W,T2]=[T1,T2]*cos(theta)

If they are collinear, just project them on a line and solve scalar equation `A=B*cos(theta)+C*sin(theta)`

Answer (score 0):

Use techniques from linear algebra to solve for the possibilities of cos(theta) and sin(theta).

```
[ T1_1  |  T2_1  |  W_1 ]
[ T1_2  |  T2_2  |  W_2 ]

[ 1     |  T2_1 / T1_1  |  W_1 / T1_1 ]
[ T1_2  |  T2_2         |  W2         ]

[ 1     |  T2_1 / T1_1                |  W_1 / T1_1             ]
[ 0     |  T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1  |  W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1 ]

[ 1     |  T2_1 / T1_1                |  W_1 / T1_1                                             ]
[ 0     |  1                          |  (W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1) / (T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1) ]

[ 1     |  0                          |  W_1 / T1_1 - T2_1 / T1_1 * (W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1) / (T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1)              ]
[ 0     |  1                          |  (W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1) / (T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1)                                         ]
```

So,

```
cos(theta) = alpha * W_1 / T1_1 - T2_1 / T1_1 * (W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1) / (T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1)
sin(theta) = alpha * (W2 - T1_2 * W_1 / T1_1) / (T2_2 - T1_2 * T2_1 / T1_1)
```

We know that

```
cos(theta)^2 + sin(theta)^2 = 1
```

Plugging the previous equations for `cos(theta)` and `sin(theta)` into that last equation, we can solve for `alpha`.  Knowing that, we can calculate the actual value of `theta` by using either arccosine or arcsine.

---

Note, that I have not checked my work in any of these steps, so I do not make any guarantees about the accuracy of the equations.  I leave that as an exercise for you.